# How to install postman on the machine which doesn't have internet?

Tags: web-services, curl, post, jax-rs, postman

I want to check web service is working or not using postman but I don't have the Internet on that machine. how can I install postman without chrome webstore?

or how should I check following web service using curl? using post request

`http://url` of web service

```
Content-Type : application/x-www-form-urlencoded 

key            value(which is to be submitted via the body of request)
inputString     again
sourceLang      eng-latn
targetLang      hin
withSuggestions  1
```

Comment: You mean, you want to install postman locally on your system without chrome?

Comment: well. i do have chrome but i don't have postman? is there any way to install?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

go to the following link as given by akhil mathew and download postman depending upon your operating system

https://www.getpostman.com/apps

Comment: if you see "Something went wrong", then at the bottom, double-click on the gray inscription

Answer (score 2):

You can simply download as an app from this [link](https://www.getpostman.com/apps) 
.In this way once installed, you dont have to be on chrome.

Other way is to clone from git repository. From here
https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support

- Then go the extensions in chrome.
- Then developer mode
- . Click Load    unpacked extension.

Comment: i think you need internet to download :P

Answer (score 1):

If you want to install postman in chrome then just go to chrome web store.

> Last week, Google announced plans to end support for Chrome Apps for Windows, Mac, and Linux users, over the next two years.

So to install postman as an application just go to this [download link](https://www.getpostman.com/apps)

Comment: i dont have internet facilty on my server to download postman from chrome web store

Comment: Download postman application from the above link corresponding to your server from any other system  and install in your server

Comment: If you find my answer as useful, just mark it as useful